# SharePoint accounts being created in SQL with $ at the end

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, administration, sql-server-2012, service-account

I'm getting the following error: (EVENT ID 3760)

```
SQL Database 'WSS_Content' on SQL Server instance 'SQLSERVER01' not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
Cannot open database "WSS_Content" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'EDSOUTH\APPSERVER01$'.
```

Even stranger is that accounts have been added to all SQL databases that are named "servername01" for each of the four servers.

From what I've read it's usually a permissions issue but nothing has been changed/added to the farm in weeks and this is the first I've seen this error or the new accounts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because you are running a services apppool as `Network Service` or `Local System`.  That account with the $ at the end is your server's identity.

You can either authorize that account to access the data or run you service applications as a user that is authorized to access the database.

if your Central Admin site root was: http://ca/ then your service account configuration can be found here: http://ca/_admin/FarmCredentialManagement.aspx

Comment: Being that I've only configured about half of the environment that makes total sense. Thanks for the help Glenn.